# Tkinter after method / threading block

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have a strange issue with TKinter `after()` method. I'm calling function `func_a()` (blocking call that takes some ms)  in main thread and `func_b()` in `after()` to read a value at regular interval. It works like a charm, I can get some updated value during `func_a()` execution

I do not need any graphical interface, so I do not use anymore TKinter, now I'm calling `func_a()` in main thread. I create a separate thread to call `func_b()`. The issue is that the call to `func_a()` stops the execution of `func_b()` separate thread. I need to wait for `func_a()` returns to have some periodic call of `func_b()`. I do not have source of `func_a()` and `func_b()` (python C bindings). But maybe some thread locking mechanism prevents `func_b()` call when `func_a()` is called.

The question is, what is implemententation behind tkinter after? How can I achieve same behavior as Tkinter `after()`: be able to call `func_b()` when `func_a()`is called, without using TKinter?

Code looks like that :

```
pos_th= threading.Thread(target=read_pos, args=(0.1,))
pos_th.daemon = True
pos_th_stop = False
pos_th.start()
func_a()

def read_pos(period):
    while not pos_th_stop :
        func_b()
        time.sleep(period)
```

Comment: ***"call to `func_a()` stops the execution of 'func_b()'"***: Remove `pos_th.daemon = True` and add `time.sleep(0.01)` after `.start()`.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change anything. I can for example call time.sleep(1) before func_a() call : func_b() will be called at periodic interval, but when func_as is called, it's not the case anymore

Comment: ***"implemententation tkinter after"***: It's outside Python, it seems `func_a()` hold the `GIL`. Read [what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython)

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L792

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, what is implemententation behind tkinter after?

When it comes down to it, it's really quite simple. Tkinter's `mainloop` method is little more than an infinite loop that waits for items to appear on the event queue. When it finds an event, it pulls it off of the queue and calls the handlers for that event.

`after` simply puts an item on the event queue. During each iteration of `mainloop` tkinter will examine the timestamp on the function added by `after`, and if the given amount of time has elapses, the function is pulled off of the queue and run.